# cl.exe won't compile in second child process

Tags: windows, cl

I am attempting to compile two files in two child process I create from Node.js' `child_process` module with `.spawn()` in parallel, basically looping over sources and spawning two shells immediately.

However only one file will be compiled and it's not always the same.
One `child_process` will return with error code 2.

Is cl.exe to be known to not being able to run two instances? I am assuming that running it sequentially will fix this problem.

**Note:** setting or unsetting /MP flag doesn't change this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cl.exe runs jsut fine in multiple process. Some flags might alter this though. In my case `/Zi` produces a program database file that cannot be accessed by more than one cl.exe.

The solution to that would be to either set `/Fs`, which forces simultaneous writes, or just not to set `/Zi`, which I then did.